Android Gradle Error: Could Not Resolve com.kaopiz
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.kaopiz:kprogresshud:1.2.0.

build.gradle
dependencies {
        implementation 'com.kaopiz:kprogresshud:1.2.0'
        // Other dependencies
    }

I have tried using alternative versions from the same repository, such as:
// implementation 'com.github.kaopiz:KProgressHUD:1.0.0'
// implementation 'com.github.Kaopiz:KProgressHUD:v1.2.0'

However, none of these attempts have resolved the issue. My allprojects repositories are configured as follows:
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        maven { url 'https://github.com/uPhyca/stetho-realm/raw/master/maven-repo' }
    }
}

What might be going wrong, and how to correctly include the com.kaopiz:kprogresshud or a working version of KProgressHUD in my project?

That library has not been maintained in over 6 years and as this issue for it shows, you can see others have encountered the same problem.

s an alternative, I used implementation 'com.github.Kaopiz:KProgressHUD:1.0', but then I had to make changes in the code base. Is there any method to use that package without altering the code base, or is there an alternative package that does not require code base changes?

You would have to search for one online.

Do you know if there is any location to download the cache file from C:\Users<username>.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com\kaopiz\kprogresshud\1.2.0?

I don't understand your question. If you have another question, please post it as a new one.

Change
implementation 'com.kaopiz:kprogresshud:1.2.0'
to
implementation 'io.github.rupinderjeet:kprogresshud:1.0.0'
https://github.com/Kaopiz/KProgressHUD/issues/74
